# How to get arrange a Huffman Tree in a specific way

Tags: c, huffman-code

I have a assignment that requires me to do Huffman encoding, but my results don't line up with the expected output.

```
// Huffman Coding in C

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_TREE_HT 50

struct MinHNode
{
    char item;
    unsigned freq;
    struct MinHNode *left, *right;
};

struct MinHeap
{
    unsigned size;
    unsigned capacity;
    struct MinHNode **array;
};

// Create nodes
struct MinHNode *newNode(char item, unsigned freq)
{
    struct MinHNode *temp = (struct MinHNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct MinHNode));

    temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
    temp->item = item;
    temp->freq = freq;

    return temp;
}

// Create min heap
struct MinHeap *createMinH(unsigned capacity)
{
    struct MinHeap *minHeap = (struct MinHeap *)malloc(sizeof(struct MinHeap));

    minHeap->size = 0;

    minHeap->capacity = capacity;

    minHeap->array = (struct MinHNode **)malloc(minHeap->capacity * sizeof(struct MinHNode *));
    return minHeap;
}

// Function to swap
void swapMinHNode(struct MinHNode **a, struct MinHNode **b)
{
    struct MinHNode *t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}

// Heapify
void minHeapify(struct MinHeap *minHeap, int idx)
{
    int smallest = idx;
    int left = 2 * idx + 1;
    int right = 2 * idx + 2;

    if (left < minHeap->size && minHeap->array[left]->freq < minHeap->array[smallest]->freq)
        smallest = left;

    if (right < minHeap->size && minHeap->array[right]->freq < minHeap->array[smallest]->freq)
        smallest = right;

    if (smallest != idx)
    {
        swapMinHNode(&minHeap->array[smallest], &minHeap->array[idx]);
        minHeapify(minHeap, smallest);
    }
}

// Check if size if 1
int checkSizeOne(struct MinHeap *minHeap)
{
    return (minHeap->size == 1);
}

// Extract min
struct MinHNode *extractMin(struct MinHeap *minHeap)
{
    struct MinHNode *temp = minHeap->array[0];
    minHeap->array[0] = minHeap->array[minHeap->size - 1];

    --minHeap->size;
    minHeapify(minHeap, 0);

    return temp;
}

// Insertion function
void insertMinHeap(struct MinHeap *minHeap, struct MinHNode *minHeapNode)
{
    ++minHeap->size;
    int i = minHeap->size - 1;

    while (i && minHeapNode->freq < minHeap->array[(i - 1) / 2]->freq)
    {
        minHeap->array[i] = minHeap->array[(i - 1) / 2];
        i = (i - 1) / 2;
    }
    minHeap->array[i] = minHeapNode;
}

void buildMinHeap(struct MinHeap *minHeap)
{
    int n = minHeap->size - 1;
    int i;

    for (i = (n - 1) / 2; i >= 0; --i)
        minHeapify(minHeap, i);
}

int isLeaf(struct MinHNode *root)
{
    return !(root->left) && !(root->right);
}

struct MinHeap *createAndBuildMinHeap(char item[], int freq[], int size)
{
    struct MinHeap *minHeap = createMinH(size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        minHeap->array[i] = newNode(item[i], freq[i]);

    minHeap->size = size;
    buildMinHeap(minHeap);

    return minHeap;
}

struct MinHNode *buildHuffmanTree(char item[], int freq[], int size)
{
    struct MinHNode *left, *right, *top;
    struct MinHeap *minHeap = createAndBuildMinHeap(item, freq, size);

    while (!checkSizeOne(minHeap))
    {
        left = extractMin(minHeap);
        right = extractMin(minHeap);

        top = newNode('$', left->freq + right->freq);

        top->left = left;
        top->right = right;

        insertMinHeap(minHeap, top);
    }
    return extractMin(minHeap);
}

// Print the array
void printArray(int arr[], int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        printf("%d", arr[i]);

    printf("\n");
}

void printHCodes(struct MinHNode *root, int arr[], int top)
{
    if (root->left)
    {
        arr[top] = 0;
        printHCodes(root->left, arr, top + 1);
    }
    if (root->right)
    {
        arr[top] = 1;
        printHCodes(root->right, arr, top + 1);
    }
    if (isLeaf(root))
    {
        printf("  %c   | ", root->item);
        printArray(arr, top);
    }
}

// Wrapper function
void HuffmanCodes(char item[], int freq[], int size)
{
    struct MinHNode *root = buildHuffmanTree(item, freq, size);

    int arr[MAX_TREE_HT], top = 0;

    printHCodes(root, arr, top);
}

int main()
{
    char arr[] = {'d', 'c', 'r', 'b', 'a'};
    int freq[] = {1, 1, 2, 2, 5};

    int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

    printf(" Char | Huffman code ");
    printf("\n--------------------\n");

    HuffmanCodes(arr, freq, size);
}
```

My output:

a: 0

r: 10

b: 110

d: 1110

c: 1111

Expected output:

a: 0

r: 10

c: 1100

d: 1101

b: 111

I know my program isn't wrong, I'm just having difficulties in the arrangement of the nodes in the tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you think that there is a preferred result? Both of your results are equally valid, and result in an optimal code. Those are two of 16 possible codes that can result from that particular tree. At each branch independently, you can assign 0 to either the left branch or the right branch, and 1 to the other branch. There are four branches, so 16 codes.

Furthermore, I can swap the symbols `b` and `r`, giving them lengths 2 and 3 instead of 3 and 2, since they have the same frequency. That doubles the number of distinct codes to 32.

Furthermore, this set of frequencies permits a topologically distinct tree that is equally optimal, with the length assignments 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, where length 1 is assigned to the symbol `a`. That tree also has 16 possible assignments of 0 or 1 to the branches.

Here are the two trees:

[image: long tree with depth 4 and short tree with depth 3]

So overall there are 48 distinct Huffman codes for that set of frequencies, all equally valid and all equally optimal.